# OxyPlot, Points not in LineSeries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, oxyplot

I have a hard time getting OxyPlot to display my data in my standalone WPF application (I use caliburn micro, and follow the MVVM pattern).

So in my Xaml I have the following:

```
<UserControl ...
xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf">
```

and later

```
<oxy:Plot Title="Winnings of Selected Player" Model="{Binding Graph1}"/>
```

In my ViewModel, I seem to have the choice to either include `using OxyPlot;` or `using OxyPlot.Wpf;`. If I do the former, I can define my `PlotModel` as follows:

```
private PlotModel _graph1;
public PlotModel Graph1 { 
    get { return _graph1;} 
    set { 
        _graph1 = value;
        Graph1.RefreshPlot(true);
    }
}

public MyViewModel() {

    Graph1 = new PlotModel();
    var FirstSeries = new LineSeries();
    FirstSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1,2));
    FirstSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1,2));

}
```

but my view does not display anything (in fact, I don't even see an 'empty graph', or the title in the view). I have tried scattering the `RefreshPlot` command all over the place, too ...

So then, I figure to try `using OxyPlot.Wpf;` instead. Then, however, I cannot add `Points` to my `LineSeries` - here's a screenshot of my IntelliSense ...

!(http://imageshack.com/a/img30/2441/cvqy.png)

So how do I populate data into my LineSeries using OxyPlot.Wpf? By the way, I still don't see an empty graph, even when I compile without adding points to the LineSeries. All examples I have looked at do this, or they write code in tha .xaml.cs code-behind file which I don't want to do.

EDIT: As dellywheel mentiones, I forgot to add the LineSeries to my PlotModel above when asking the question, so the constructor above should contain the line

```
Graph1.Series.Add(FirstSeries);
```

But that was just in typing the question, ofc not the real problem ...

Answer (score 1):

You havent added the LineSeries to the Graph and the Graph is Graph1 not Graph
Try

```
public MyViewModel(){
     Graph1 = new PlotModel();
     var firstSeries = new LineSeries();
     firstSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 2));
     firstSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 2));
     Graph1.Series.Add(firstSeries);
  }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Edited question. That was just a blunder in typing it up. Real question is why OxyPlot.Wpf LineSeries has no Points.

Comment: Its just a wrapper class for WPF you use OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries for your graph http://www.oxyplot.org/doc/HelloWpf.html

Comment: This is a very partial answer ... OK so I use OxyPlot, but even if I do as I said above I still don't get a graph. Even if the Binding were not working, should I not at least get an 'empty graph' with title in my view?

Comment: Also, the examples have the line `xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.codeplex.com"` in the header of the Xaml - if I do that it does not compile, I have to use `xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"` ... Does that have something to do with the fact that I cannot install the package via nuget, but reference the .dll's directly (i.e., I downloaded the files from the OxyPlot webpage, and added the .dll references for OxyPlot.dll and Oxyplot.Wpf.dll manually to my solution)?